# Windows Phone 8 (icon inside longlistselector datatemplate issue)

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have an application which uses a data template to display items in a longlistselector. Inside the data template there are two images. One of the images, has a loaded event handler which checks if the image should be visible or not. This works perfectly and the image doesn't show up when not needed however when the user locks the screen and unlocks it or when they press the windows key and then return to the app it's all messed up. The image appears on places that it shouldn't. When normally navigating this does not occur. Also the image loaded event doesn't trigger when the user unlocks the phone or comes back after having pressed the windows key. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DataBinding to control the visibility (bind each item to an ItemViewModel)and also you could listen for the Application::Activated event if for some reason your UI state needs refreshing.

Comment: How can I easily use databinding for something so complicated? Also I checked the Application::Activated event nothing is there. As a matter of fact nothing seems to be running when the device gets locked and unlocked so I have no idea what causes this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use visibility converter to manage that it will work good

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int count = (int)value;
            if (count != 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: How could I use that to make the image visible using some info available in the datacontext of the image? So this is normal behaviour(the one i explained above)?

Comment: @ΜάριοςΘεοφάνους you have to bind the data to xaml template, do you want sample code?

Comment: Yeah I would really like some sample code. Also if you could also add some xaml sample code that would be great. This issue is tormenting me and I have not found an answer anywhere :/ I really appreciate your help :D